# MKMapView "Legal" Label necessary for custom maps?

Tags: ios, maps, mkmapview, mktileoverlay

I´m using *MKMapView* for displaying *MKTileOverlays*. The overlays are drawn by myself and i don't show any map data from Apple or Google. Do I need the "Legal" label on top of the map? I only use the *MKMapView* to display custom tiles and put some custom annotations on it. Do I really need the legal patch here? Will my app be rejected if I drop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legal link is required by Apple and there is some possibility that your app will get rejected if you remove it by using private class i.e. (if you loop the subviews of the map for MKAttributedLabel and remove/hide it). Your case is a bit more challenging of their rules due to the usage of tiles, but on a previous project of mine, where I needed a small mapView and the link was appearing quite bad on that small area, I extended the bottom area of the map a bit so that link is obscured by the view in front of it. The app got published without a problem.

Comment: Ok, hiding the link is one of my ideas. But it is a technical decision to use the map view or create a tile based view with sprite kit or something. so i have to be sure if it will be rejected before i do much of work...